# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\operatorname{Re}\left(z^{n}\right)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given that $z$ is a non real complex number such that $|z|\leq 1$ ,then under what conditions the series $\sum \frac{Re\left(z^{n}\right)}{n}$ is absolutely and conditionally convergent?

My try:
Case $1.$ Let $|z|<1$ and say $|z|=r$
Letting $z=re^{i\theta}$

We get $$\operatorname{Re}(z^n)=r^n\cos(n \theta)$$

So the series is $$\sum \frac{r^n\cos(n \theta)}{n}$$

Taking $$b_n=\left|\frac{r^n\cos(n \theta)}{n}\right|$$
I have applied absolute ratio test as follows:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}\right|=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} r\left|\frac{\cos (n+1) \theta}{\cos (n \theta)}\right|$$

But I am not sure of this limit.

Comment: Compare it to $\sum r^n/n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $|z| < 1,$ then the series is absolutely convergent by comparison with $\sum \frac{|z|^n}{n}.$ For $z=1,$ the series is divergent. For all other $z$ the series is conditionally convergent, by partial summation.

Comment: As far as my knowledge, if a series is convergent and not absolutely convergent, then we say it is conditionally convergent. So when $|z|=1$ i took the help of partial summation based on the idea of Dirchlet's test. But how to prove it is conditionally convergent?